# What can be stored in a resource.resx file?

Tags: c#, resources

In a C# project, is it possible to store more than just strings in the resources.resx file? Specifically, I was curious to know if I could take a simple data-object defined in my project, and store an instance of it in the resource file to pull out during runtime.

I figure I probably can do this if I serialize my object first, then put the serializer output in the resource file, but I was hoping to be able to have the object strongly-typed when I pull it out.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

So you could store your object as a binary or XML file and deserialize it back but a resource file seems uncommon place to store such things.

Comment: Yeah, I figured as much... I was just hoping to be able to have a default object stored, so that if a certain reflection operation failed, I could have a default object to fall back on... but then again, storing an object in a resource file is probably exactly like hardcoding it anyways.

Comment: where else would you store application images like icon images from files the user added inside the application?